# Access image through web address without including the extension

Tags: html, webserver

I've seen this around the web before but I cannot wrap my mind around how it works.  Hopefully someone can help explain this.

Lets say we have a picture at this address.  http://www.website.com/image-150x150.jpg

How can I set it up so if you go to http://www.website.com/image-150x150 it shows that picture?

So the only difference is I do not have to include the extension, ie. *.jpg.

On top of all this, I want to be able to refrence it like this as well:

```
<img src="http://www.website.com/image-150x150" />
```

Comment: URL rewriting or a controller that serves the image.

Comment: What if we have a site that serves 100,000s of images in this fashion?

Comment: What server are you using?It's just a matter of configuring the server to set image/jpeg content type header when serving your images

Comment: Windows Server 2008 IIS 7

Comment: I got no experience with IIS but according to http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6286/modifying-or-adding-custom-mime-types-to-windows-hosting-accounts you can get it working.

Comment: Locally hosted, not using any 3rd party companies.

Comment: web.config is not godaddy specific ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache, you need to add a `.htaccess` rule similiar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\.jpg $1
```

In the case of IIS (which I haven't used at all!), consider using something like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="rewrite php">
            <!--Removes the .php extension for all pages.-->
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="(.*).jpg" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.jpg" />
        </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I'm sure that you have to change this based on your need.

Comment: IIS7 equilivent? (web.config)

Comment: Edited my answer... have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the extension and reference it with the img tag and it should work. Since the encoding is of jpeg format and the img tag accepts this encoding, it should be able to convert & display the correct image.